# Objective-c with sql-lite on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can you give me a good start for this?
Thanks!

---

Edit:
The accepted answer was the best, because if you would like to use SQLite on iPhone, in 90% of the cases I would suggest CoreData.
Here's another good link where you can start:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Core-Data to handle SQL-Lite on the iPhone.
Check these tutorials, they helped me a lot:
http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/08/core-data-part-1-an-introduction.html

Regards,
Paul Peelem

Comment: Though Core Data uses SQLite today, there is no guarantee that it will do so in a future release.  To use SQLite and to use Core Data for persistent storage are clearly two different solutions.

I have an application that I ported to the iPhone that uses an SQL database on another platform. The effort that would have been required to convert this application to use Core Data would have been prohibitive. To simply convert it to another SQL library was trivial.

-t

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul's answer. If you don't want to use CoreData though, you can still use straight *pure C* **SQLite API**. There is a lot of documentation on the issue. You can check the C/C++ [examples](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) on SQLite's website.

Answer (score 1):

there is a good c library. libsqlite3.dylib. you can find all needed documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can give this SQLite ORM a shot https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

It provides all of the basic functionality that you will need.